# Find all real matrices $A$ such that $A^2 = \mathrm{diag}(1,1,2,3,5,8,13)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{7 \times 7} (\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$A^2= \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&3&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&5&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&8&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&13\end{pmatrix} $$

How many matrices, which satisfy this condition could you find?

My friend told to me, that the correct answer is infinity. But I can find only one:

$$A^2= \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&\sqrt{2}&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&\sqrt{3}&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&\sqrt{5}&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&\sqrt{8}&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&\sqrt{13} \end{pmatrix} $$

I will grateful for hints, how find any other examples. I suppose that $A$ should depend from parametr which don't govern on product $A \cdot A$.

Comment: Can you find only one solution to $a^2=1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \varphi & \sin \varphi & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \sin \varphi & -\cos \varphi & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 &  0& 0& \ldots &  0\\ \vdots &  \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\ 0 &  0& 0& \ldots &  0 \end{pmatrix}^2 = ?$$

Comment: This is an elegant proof, but I was thinking if somehow the properties of Fibonacci numbers could be used to reach such a conclusion... or was it just to divert our mind from the real problem at hand?

Comment: @abi: :-) true, just to divert us...

Comment: @AbishankaSaha It is a diversion. All that matter here are that (a) $A^2$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix (b) 1 is the only repeated eigenvalue of $A^2$. If you are familiar with Jordan normal form, it can be proved that every $A$ that produces the given square is either of the form $\mathrm{diag}(\pm I_2, DU)$ or $\mathrm{diag}(R, DU)$, where $D=\mathrm{diag}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{8},\sqrt{13})$, $U$ is an $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ diagonal matrix where each diagonal entry is equal to $\pm1$ and $R$ is a matrix of the form $\pmatrix{\cos\varphi&\sin\varphi\\ \sin\varphi&-\cos\varphi}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \varphi & \sin \varphi & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ \sin \varphi & -\cos \varphi & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 &  0& 0& \ldots &  0\\ \vdots &  \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\ 0 &  0& 0& \ldots &  0 \end{pmatrix}^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 0 &  0& 0& \ldots &  0\\ \vdots &  \vdots& \vdots& \ddots &  \vdots\\ 0 &  0& 0& \ldots &  0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Additionaly I noticed that

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \varphi & \sin \varphi & 0 \\ \sin \varphi & -\cos \varphi & 0 \\ 0 &  0& x \end{pmatrix} ^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 &  0& x^2 \end{pmatrix} $$ 
so I suppose that we can take

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} \cos \varphi&\sin \varphi &0&0&0&0&0\\\sin \varphi&-\cos \varphi&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&\sqrt{2}&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&\sqrt{3}&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&\sqrt{5}&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&\sqrt{8}&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0&\sqrt{13} \end{pmatrix} $$

Of course, $\varphi$ is any so we have infinity matrices.

Comment: Good! but as long as we're here, did you see my comment on your question?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now I understood what have you mean.

Comment: If you ask, how many **diagonal** matrices then you have $2^7=128$. Do you know why?

Comment: No, I don't know why.